# What are "interconvertible functions"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, terminology, periodic-functions

I was studying periodic functions and found this statement:

> If fundamental period of $f(x)= T$ and fundamental period of $g(x)= T'$,
> then fundamental period of $f(x)\pm g(x)=\operatorname{LCM}(T,T')$.
>
> (NOTE: Not applicable if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are interconvertible functions.)

What are "interconvertible functions"?

Comment: It could be something defined earlier in the textbook. Or, if that's a translation by any chance, it would help to know what the word was in the original language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $$ f(x) = \cos{\cos x} + \cos{\sin x}  $$
If you observe the functions seperately (let them be $g,h$ ) , we observe that the fundamental period is $π$ for both of them seperately as $ g(x+π) = g(x) $
And $ h(x+π) = h(x) $
But when you consider $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$
You would observe that $ f(x+π/2) = f(x) $
And hence by definition of " Fundamental Period " ,  it is $π/2$ for $f(x)$ while the LCM of the Fundamental Periods of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ is $π$ only.
This is due to the " interconversion between functions " that is meant there . They are not a distinct class of function like exponential, logarithmic etc . In my example it was the usage of trigonometry identities .